# http get request timeout

Tags: php, sockets, http, get

I'm trying to send http request via socket. I've written the follosing code:

```
$sock = fsockopen('ooooo.ru', 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
fputs($sock, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fputs($sock, "Host: http://ooooo.ru/\r\n");
fputs($sock, "Content-type: text/html\r\n");
echo fgets($sock);
```

But I've a timeout error. But I can see the `ooooo.ru` via browser correctly. Why it's occuring?

Comment: Why are you sending a content-type on a GET request?

Comment: Why are you dealing with raw HTTP anyway? PHP has the [cURL library](http://php.net/curl).

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a blank line to indicate the end of your HTTP request header, and you should not send a content-type when you don't have a request body to specify the type of.

Replace `fputs($sock, "Content-type: text/html\r\n");` with `fputs($sock, "\r\n");`

The host also needs to be a host name and not a URL.

Replace `fputs($sock, "Host: http://ooooo.ru/\r\n");` with `fputs($sock, "Host: ooooo.ru\r\n");`

Better yet, stop trying to write HTTP yourself and use the [cURL library](http://php.net/curl).